# reactivate pycharm virtual environment after reinstall

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv, importerror

I set a virtual environment for one of my PyCharm projects a while ago. At some point, I uninstalled Anaconda and then reinstalled it. I now get module import errors when trying to compile my project, and I believe I need to reactivate the environment, since I get this error when I load the `python.exe` file in the venv folder:

> "This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the
> environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load."

How do I reactivate the environment? There is a  folder in the directory of my project, with an activate.bat file, but running this does not appear to do anything.

How do I (re)activate an existing virtual environment in a specific directory for my project? I'm aware of the `conda activate` command, but I am still unsure how to add an existing one in my project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out how to do this, so I reinstalled all (specific versions of) packages I was using on my fresh Anaconda build.